# Suggestions for Image Cropper for profile picture liferay

Tags: jquery, html, image, liferay

I know this is dumb question but is anyone here can suggest image uploader with cropper tool like facebook cropper tool but for Liferay

I've now used cropper from [fengyuanchen](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) cropper tool,
Can suggest here for better cropper and simple tool

> **Only i need is cropper with image uploader and fixed 1x1 ratio**

Thanks and advance... You can closed this if this is duplicate question but give a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it and this is what i looking for

[Simple Tool for Image cropper](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Canvas-Based-Image-Cropping-Plugin-Simple-Cropper.html)